# Mapproxy working with Maptiler

Tags: mapproxy, maptiler

I am trying to set up Mapproxy with Maptiler as a source for OSM data.
The configuration works well using Google Satellite Images and Sentinel data but somehow it does not work with Maptiler server.
This is google Satellite Image via Mapproxy:

[image]

This is the Maptiler OSM image using Maptiler server:

[image]

The size of both images are 512x512. The bounding box is 400 meters by 400 meters.
This is my configuration file for Mapproxy

```
  osm_source:
    type: tile
    concurrent_requests: 1
    grid: GLOBAL_WEBMERCATOR
    url: http://xx.xx.x.xxx:xxxx/api/maps/basic/%(z)s/%(x)s/%(y)s.png
  google_satellite_source:
    type: tile
    url: https://mt2.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x=%(x)s&y=%(y)s&z=%(z)s
    grid: GLOBAL_WEBMERCATOR
    transparent: true
    on_error:
       404:
          response: transparent
          cache: False
grids:
  webmercator:
    base: GLOBAL_WEBMERCATOR
    origin: 'sw'
```